# How to delete only the selected message inside a #Chat using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this chat which I am trying to make. Everything works ok so far but when i try to delete the message which i clicked using the Yes button it deletes all the messages if there are more.

Also i would like the one that is clicked to get background:#ccc,I tried to use .css() but it colors every message that is clicked and remains like that .
For exemple if i click **message 1** make it background:#ccc , and if i click **message 2** make it background:#ccc and remove the background:#ccc from **message 1**

Can anyone explain to me how to fix it ??Thank you.

This is my code

```
         $("#chat").on("click", ".mesaj", function(){
          console.log("click works on class");
          $("#yes").click(function(){
          $(".mesaj").remove();
          $("#delPop").hide();

        });

        $("#delPop").show();
        $("#no").on("click", function(){
        $("#delPop").hide();
    });

});
```

My chat:https://jsfiddle.net/azfwuzad/9/

Comment: use relative addressing, like `$(this).hide();`

Comment: i need to remove the message not hide it , the problem is it removes every message not only the clicked one .

Comment: `$(this).remove();` inside the click event removes all of them? are you sure?

Comment: @dandavis depends which click event , if its inside the button it removes the button **yes**, if its inside the #chat click event it removes all of them if you have more .atleast that what i saw , but now i fixed it . Thank you tho .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/azfwuzad/12/)

You basically need to mark the selected message with class 'selected'

```
$(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
```

and then remove that class only

```
    $("#yes").one("click", function(){
         $(".mesaj.selected").remove();
         $("#delPop").hide();   
    });

    $("#no").one("click", function(){
        $("#delPop").hide();
    });
```

[Alternative way](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/azfwuzad/14/) of doing this could be to just remember which message you have clicked on

```
  var self = $(this);
```

and

```
    $("#yes").one("click", function(){
         $(".mesaj.selected").remove();
         $("#delPop").hide();   
    });
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it , but is there a way to make it work without adding class selected ? Since the message is being created as a class already.

Comment: @azazutesting it depends whether you want to allow multiple messages to be selected and deleted or not.

Comment: @azazutesting try this updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/azfwuzad/14/

Comment: Thanks a lot ,yes thats easier and more understanding for me since im new to this .

Comment: Hey, i just realised it also deletes the message even if u click no ,is it cuz i didnt mark it with a selected class like u said first time ? 


Yeah , its cuz of that , fixed it now . Ty

Answer (score 3):

You can do like

```
$("#chat").on("click", ".mesaj", function(){
var element = $(this);
console.log("Merge click clasa");
$("#yes").click(function(){
     $(element).remove();
     $("#delPop").hide();

    });

    $("#delPop").show();
    $("#no").on("click", function(){
        $("#delPop").hide();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `var msg = $(this)` inside your .mesaj click function, and reference it inside your #yes click function:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdmtu4f4/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#chat").on("click", ".mesaj", function(){
var that = this
console.log("Merge click clasa");
$("#yes").click(function(){
     $(that).remove();
     $("#delPop").hide();

    });
```

hope helps :)